# Somar valores com PROCV

Tags: microsoft-excel, soma, procv

Tenho uma folha de Excel com a gastos mensais por alimento. O objetivo é, numa folha à parte, calcular a soma de cada alimento em todos os meses.
Com a fórmula que estou a utilizar neste momento `=SOMA(PROCV(A3;Alimentos!C3:K3000;7;0))`, apenas me está a ir buscar o valor relativo ao primeiro mês e não a soma de todos os meses.

Para esclarecer a fórmula:

1. `A3` é o alimento que estou a procurar;
2. `Alimentos!C3:K3000` é o range da tabela onde estou a procurar os dados;
3. Finalmente o 7 será o índice da coluna onde está o valor gasto por mês.

Penso que não há informação extra.

Comment: Se eu entendi corretamente, o que você precisa utilizar é a função SOMASE, aqui tem um tutorial https://ninjadoexcel.com.br/aula-como-utilizar-a-funcao-somase-excel/

Answer (score 0):

Bem simples de se resolver, utilize o **SOMASE**:

```
=SOMASE(Alimentos!J:J;A3)
```

Com essa formula você irá somar todos os valores da coluna J (no caso o valor 7 do procv) na aba Alimentos! que contenham o valor da celula A3.